# How to increase load on cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes and 4 clients sending requests to the cluster. Requests are sent asynchronously. Here's snippet of code responsible for sending requests

```
import com.datastax.driver.core._
import com.datastax.driver.core.policies.{DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy, TokenAwarePolicy}
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select.Where
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.{Batch, QueryBuilder}

val query =
    QueryBuilder.
        insertInto(keyspace, tableName).
        values(columnNames, columnValues)
session.executeAsync(query)

def setupSession(config: Config): Session = {
    val port: Int = config.getInt(CassandraKeyValueStorage.PortKey)
    val addresses: Array[String] = config.getString(CassandraKeyValueStorage.HostsKey).split(",")
    addresses.
        foldLeft(Cluster.builder)(_ addContactPoints _).
        withPort(port).
        withPoolingOptions(
            new PoolingOptions().
            setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 1280).
            setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.REMOTE, 32000).
            setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 1280).
            setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance.LOCAL, 32000)).
        withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())).
        build.
        connect
}
```

As have been shown I had changed limits to higher numbers so I expect them not to slow down the client.

However I observe strange behavior. Here are statistics for requests sent by clients (`time speed1 speed2 speed3 speed4 total_speed`):

```
09:30   0.774   0.25    0.456   0.774   2.254
10:00   1.082   0.354   0.302   0.744   2.482
10:30   1.04    0.548   0.774   0.266   2.628
11:00   0.962   0.7     0.234   0.558   2.454
11:30   0.69    0.622   0.44    0.806   2.558
12:00   0.34    0.432   0.416   1.056   2.244
12:30   0.346   0.414   0.872   0.768   2.4
13:00   0.458   0.428   0.73    0.98    2.596
13:30   0.222   0.47    0.798   0.652   2.142
14:00   0.59    1.084   0.748   0.172   2.594
14:30   0.328   0.806   1.018   0.458   2.61
15:00   0.436   0.5     1.134   0.722   2.792
15:30   0.52    0.258   0.676   0.928   2.382
16:00   0.406   0.202   0.508   0.798   1.914
```

From it it's clear that total speed is bounded with some value, while clients are able to send more data. At the same time CPU idle is about 20% on cassandra boxes, so it is not so hard loaded. I cannot understand what prevents clients from sending more data. I think that network bandwidth is not the reason as everything happens inside one region on google cloud engine and current load is about 30 Mb/s (with a bound of 1 Gb/s).

Comment: "everything happens inside one region on google cloud engine" - So all 3 nodes and the application servers are in the same region on google cloud?

Comment: @ChrisGerlt exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I'd adviced is to try to run 2 client instances on the same box. If it increases the total traffic from that box approximately twice then try to adjust connection threading settings. I suppose it might be in the Pooling options. What are the defaults there BTW?

It might also depend on threading settings on the Cassandra side, but I am not sure it is your case.

Additionally it is worth to check ping time from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

Any cluster is going to have a maximum throughput for a given set of hardware, network conditions, and schema used.

To find that maximum throughput, I generally use clients that will issue commands using a thread pool of a configurable size.  This allows you to control the maximum number of operations in flight at any given time, and you can then adjust the size of the thread pool until you get the maximum throughput.  You'll know you've reached it when increasing the number of threads results in no increase in throughput, but does result in increased latency per transaction.

You don't want to use clients that just try to issue as many requests as they can since then you may get various queues to fill up or overflow, requests to start timing out, etc., and that will muddy the picture of what you're trying to measure.